# Intent App Chooser shouldnt start the app, should return the app information

Tags: android, android-intent

I am new to android development. I want to get an intent of an app, which has been chosen by the user via a chooser. The following is my Code.

```
        Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
        mainIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);           

        Intent chooser = Intent.createChooser(mainIntent, "title");
        startActivity(chooser); //I don't want to start the intent ... just to know which one user chose
```

The problem is that every time the user selects an app, it will be started. But I want only the intent/information of the app chosen. I will start the app later.

Hope you know what I mean.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to build a chooser yourself by retrieving relevant targets with `PackageManager.queryIntentActivities()` and then building your own dialog from it.